# Recursively link files from one folder to another

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following structure:

```
/foo
/foo/pages
/foo/pages/page1
              file100.txt
              file101.txt
/foo/pages/page1/item1
              file199.txt
/foo/pages/page2
              filefoo202.txt
              bar3.txt
/foo/pages/page3
/foo/bar
```

I want to get every file which ends in `.txt` in `/foo/pages` and create a symbolic link in `/foo/bar`. The command will be executed from `/foo`.

The final outcome in `/foo/bar` would be:

```
/foo/bar
    file100.txt
    file101.txt
    file199.txt
    filefoo202.txt
    bar3.txt
```

Note: I am using Linux / Bash

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Corrected slashes. I am struggling to do it with find, extract the name, etc. but I am wondering if it is an easy way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

```
find foo -type f -exec ln -s ../../{} foo/bar/ \;
```

relative symbolic link is from where the file is created.

Otherwise absolute symbolic link :

```
find foo -type f -exec ln -s "$PWD"/{} foo/bar/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd bar  # maybe 'mkdir bar' before
for i in ../pages/*.txt
do
  ln -s "$i"
done
```

Comment: This gives no recursion and does not create links in /foo/bar

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't.  You specify that you start in `/foo/`.  I `cd` into `bar` at the beginning.  Then I create symlinks pointing to each of `../pages/*.txt`.  These are created where I am with the basename of the target.  I don't see what "recursion" you are expecting, though.

Comment: Ah, I now see that you also have deeply nested structures.  My solution will only solve the issue for the first layer.  Your own answer walks the tree down properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `find ../pages/ -name "*.txt"`
do
    ln -s "$i" 
done
```

Comment: You don't need that `sed` stuff.  A simple `ln -s "$i"` is enough.  But you need the quotes around `$i` in case any file has a space in it.

Comment: Duly noted, much easier to read without the sed stuff and double quotes used to ensure that spaces are not an issue. Thanks

Comment: Omitting the quotes without good reason has several drawbacks.  First, there *might* be a file with spaces in it.  Maybe just by accident, maybe in a later situation.  Second, other developers reviewing your code might be confused by why you omit them because omitting them means you want another evaluation step of the variable's contents.  Third, you might develop the habit of omitting them while omitting them in most cases is not beneficial and in many a plain bug.  Don't forget that an answer given here should not just solve your special situation.